# How does QVC stream it's channel to its website?

Tags: video-streaming, magento-1.7

I have general about how to stream TV to a website. I have been asked by a shopping channel if would be possible to integrate live channel feeds onto their site in the same way the QVC does.

They are currently using Magento as their platform but I am not sure what QVC use.

I would be interested to know if anyone has any thoughts or ideas on this please...

Here is a link to what I am referring to. I'm not exactly sure that it is a live stream

http://www.qvcuk.com/LiveShowDisplay?storeId=10252&catalogId=10152&langId=-2

Comment: They probably use a CDN service like Akamai or Limelight.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the reply... Could you provide a link to these services so I can investigate further please?

Comment: www.akamai.com, www.limelight.com